# Angular 6 Get Query Param with '#"

Tags: angular, routes

So I am testing a Facebook authentication in my app and once I log into Facebook it redirects to my URL like this "http://localhost:4200/facebook-auth#access_token=MYACCESSTOKEN"

I try and access the parameter but it returns null.

`const accessToken: string = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('access_token');`

In testing if i change the URL to use a "?" instead of a "#" it works. But i don't have control of the redirect from Facebook. Not sure why I can't access it when it uses a "#"?

Comment: in mine app I use this `this.route.queryParams.subscribe` and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out it is considered a fragment not a query param.

`this.route.snapshot.fragment;`